# I want to extract data between sentences and send it to a file

Tags: bash, perl

I have a Time log file that begins with the statement:

```
N:5,Image: 320 420,SF:2
```

then..

```
0.192
9.1829
879.08
```

...and then

```
N:100, Image 640 480 sf2
0.98
56.973
230.988
```

With the value of `N` incrementing every time.

I want to extract the time (floating-point numbers) into a file for `N`= 5 then `N` = 10

this is the code that i had written

```
use strict;

use warnings;

#open(FH, "out_put/Time_log1.txt");

#    my $line =<FH>;

#    my @b =<FH>;

#    foreach my $line (@b)

 #   {

 #   perl -i.bak -ne print unless /\N:5/\b(.*?)/\bN:10\b/ 

 #   print $line >Time_log;

#}
open(FIL, "out_put/Time_log1.txt");

my $sum = 0;

my $count = 0;

my $avg =0;

foreach( <FIL> ) {chomp; $sum += $_;$count++;}

$avg=$sum/$count;

close(FIL);

print "Sum = $sum\n";

print "avg is = $avg\n";
```

Comment: What have you done so far and where are you stuck, please?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, show us specifically what you did so we can help you along. **You start it, and then we help. We don't write it for you.** Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: I have solution, but it says question has been closed?...why so

Comment: use strict;
use warnings;
 
my $filename = 'in.txt';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

open(my $fh1, '>', 'output.txt');
 
while (my $row = <$fh>) {
  chomp $row;
  if($row=~/N:(\d+)/)
 {
  if($1%5==0)
  {
  print $fh1 scalar <$fh>;
  print $fh1 scalar <$fh>;
  print $fh1 scalar <$fh>;
  }
 }
}

close $fh1;

Comment: @user3388005: It is closed because Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, but not a helpdesk. For the Q&A site to function and continue being successful, questions must be of high enough quality, as well as answers. Otherwise no-one after the OP will find the answers useful. The specific reason for this case is in the yellow box above the comments. In short OP is just asking for some code, and doesn't explain what is wrong - so, in turn, there are no meaningful search terms that would ever make your answer useful for anyone but the OP.

Comment: use strict;
use warnings;
#open(FH, "out_put/Time_log1.txt");
#    my $line =<FH>;
#    my @b =<FH>;
#    foreach my $line (@b)
 #   {
 #   perl -i.bak -ne print unless /\N:5/\b(.*?)/\bN:10\b/ 
 #   print $line >Time_log;
#}
open(FIL, "out_put/Time_log1.txt");
my $sum = 0;
my $count = 0;
my $avg =0;
foreach( <FIL> ) {chomp; $sum += $_;$count++;}
$avg=$sum/$count;
close(FIL);
print "Sum = $sum\n";
print "avg is = $avg\n";

Comment: That is quite odd code, given your problem, it doesn't really fit at all other than that it reads numbers from a file - looks like just some random script you are hoping to adapt?. As well as posting the script, could you clarify what you are having problems with when writing the code? If we can identify which bit of *Perl* knowledge would allow you to confidently hack the script into shape, this is better IMO than just writing the answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so given what you're trying to do - looks like you're summing values following an 'N' line:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %n_values;
my %n_count;
my $current_n = 0;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if (m/\AN:\d+/) {
        ($current_n) = (m/\AN:(\d+)/);
    }

    my ($value) = (m/([\d\.]+)/);
    if ( defined $value ) {
        $n_values{$current_n} += $value;
        $n_count{$current_n}++;
    }
}

foreach my $n ( keys %n_values ) {
    print "N: $n value: $n_values{$n}\n";
}

__DATA__
N:5,Image: 320 420,SF:2 
0.192
9.1829
879.08
N:100, Image 640 480 sf2
0.98
56.973
230.988
```

This will cycle through the contents of `DATA`, reading one line at a time, and setting `$current_n` each time it sees a line starting `N:`. A hash is updated for `$current_n` as long as there's a value there to add.

Which should do the trick, although it doesn't do much in the way of error checking e.g. invalid values in the file.